# Is a graphical representation of Season 7's timeline available?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Partially inspired by [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/78541/33910), I admit that I find Season 7's timeline 
quite confusing.

Is a timeline description of the first 4 episodes available? Something that includes the major protagonists and their storylines in comparison to one another, if possible. [This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7311/44057) is something like I have in mind.

Comment: to the downvoter, can I ask why? is this off-topic?

Comment: [I haven't Downvoted](http://imgur.com/a/bxw3K) but People can downvote for whatever reason, even if it is on-topic. They can DV if they find your question poor or uninteresting. That's precisely why DV are anonymous

Comment: @Aegon I know, it's that I would like to incentivize explaining, so that maybe I can try to fix it.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your question is somewhat irrelevant. We're in uncharted territory as far as the books are concerned, and there is no specific mention of times and dates in the show to help us place everything. At best, we can tell you the **order** of the events (not the time between them). But the order of the scenes in the show is already chronological (where it is important. The order of two completely unrelated scenes does not matter at all to understand the show). The best answer we can give you is the order of scenes as they occur in the show, which is a pointless exercise.

Comment: Just to prove my point: From what we have seen so far, **Sam's storyline** is virtually unrelated to anything else. They could've shown all of Sam's scenes (so far) in a single episode, or spread it out over 4 episodes. It does not matter. The **only** thing that makes Sam "relevant" (to the timeline) is that he sends the message to Jon about the dragonglass in Dragonstone. Other than that, it's **irrelevant** when his actions take place in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @Federico The thing about passage of time on the *show*, rather than the books is that there is no regard for consistency, or any detail as to how much time has passed. Sometimes weeks or months pass for one character between one episode and the next, and only some days for another character. The only thing that we can say with some confidence is that roughly a year passes by for our characters in the show, from the start of a season to the start of the next one (so it matches real, non-fictional chronology in that sense, since the seasons take a year each to make and release).

Comment: In other words: one could only really estimate passage of time for these things, and I'm sure the creative team don't even have a number on it for every event, they just come up with the events. You'd have to wait for an officially produced timeline, which in all likelihood wouldn't be made until prior to the release of the next season.

Comment: @GhotiandChips and Flater, thanks. I see your point. Do you think that if I reword this to be about an estimate of the time passing between different events in the various episodes, would it be salvageable?

Comment: @Federico The salvageability of the question was not part of the point I was bringing up. It was more to say that I don't doubt you will have a tricky time getting a satisfactory answer for this, either forever or until HBO releases an infographic about this.

Comment: Can't do a graph right now but you might be interested in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/freefolk/comments/6rba7o/understanding_season_7_travel_times_a_timeline) about the timeline

Comment: @Federico: It'd be a more pertinent question, but imo still mostly opinion-based. And asking for a full analysis of all scenes in the season, including observing geographical locations, speed of travel (relative to the traveling party and the terrain) is **massive** for a single question. Maybe ask separate questions about the specific scenes you're interested in, to at least narrow it down. E.g. the question about Danaerys' response time in S07E06 is much more narrow than a full season analysis (note that that specific timespan has already been discussd a few times)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is: https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline#Season_7_-_304_AC

There is everything that can be derived from the TV show. The TV show does give only few clues regarding the timing of events.